# Python Writing a Dictionary to Text File isn't producing correct output

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

I have a dictionary as such -

`d = {"Dave":("Male", "96"), "Alice":("Female", "98")}`

I want to write it to a text file in such a format -

```
Dave
Male
96
Alice
Female
98
```

This is my current code -

```
d = {"Dave":("Male", "96"), "Alice":("Female", "98")}

with open("dictionary.txt", 'w') as f:
    for key, value in d.items():
    f.write('%s \n %s \n' % (key, value))
```

It is, however, producing the following output in the text file:

```
Dave 
  ('Male', '96') 
 Alice 
  ('Female', '98')
```

How can I adjust this?
Please help! Thanks.

Comment: The value of each dict item is a tuple. Instead of writing the tuple, write each element of the tuple using `value[0]` and `value[1]`.

Comment: Use another loop to print out each member of the tuple

Comment: @jeffcarey please refer to my own answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you convert a `tuple` to a `str` using formatting, you get the *representation* of the tuple, which is (roughly, there are 2 methods `__str__` and `__repr__` actually) what python prints when you `print` the item in the console.

To get elements without the tuple decorations, you have to *unpack* the tuple. One option (using `format`):

```
for key, value in d.items():
    f.write("{}\n{}\n{}\n".format(key,*value))
```

`*` unpacks the elements of `value` into 2 elements. `format` does the rest

An even more compact way would be to multiply the format string by 3 (less copy/paste)

```
for key, value in d.items():
    f.write(("{}\n"*3).format(key,*value))
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the `i in range` method that iterates for every value in every key -

```
d = {"Dave":("Male", "96"), "Alice":("Female", "98")}

with open("dictionary.txt", 'w') as f:
    for key, value in d.items():
        for x in range(0,2):
            f.write('%s \n %s \n' % (key, value[x]))
```

Comment: This would repeat the name every second line.

Comment: Close. Write the key in the outer loop, then the values in the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

The following works in Python 3.6:

```
d = {"Dave":("Male", "96"), "Alice":("Female", "98")}
with open('dictionary.txt', mode='w') as f:
    for name, (sex, age) in d.items():
        f.write(f'{name}\n{sex}\n{age}\n')
```

You can unpack the tuple at the top of the `for` loop.  Additionally, in Python 3.6, you can use the [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) mechanism to directly interpolate variable values into strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
 d = {"Dave":("Male", "96"), "Alice":("Female", "98")}
 with open("dictionary.txt", 'w') as f:
    for key in d.keys():
        f.write('%s \n' % (key))
        for v in d[key]:
           f.write('%s \n' % (v))
```